# Getting 500 Internal Server error on sending the token and requesting SAS URI

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I am passing token as :

```
    String access_token = object.get("access_token").toString();
    System.out.println("Access Token -------->" + access_token);
    System.out.println("Decoded Access Token --------> " +URLDecoder.decode(access_token));
    //String basicAuth = "Basic "+ new String(new Base64().encode(access_token.getBytes()));
    CreateSubmissionMetadata(access_token);

public static void CreateSubmissionMetadata (String access_token) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        String sysdevEndPoint = "https://devicesigningservice.cloudapp.net/api/signing/devices";
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(sysdevEndPoint);
        StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"TestHarnessType\": \"HLK\",\"OSSelections\": [{\"OS\",\"Windows 7\"},{\"OS\",\"Windows 8\"},{\"OS\",\"Windows 8.1\"},{\"OS\",\"Windows 10\"}],\"ProductName\":\"Test Name\",\"InitialUploadFileSize\": <size>}");
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        System.out.println("Sending token ---->"+ access_token);
        request.setHeader("Authorization: Bearer ", access_token);
        Log.d("DEBUG", "HEADERS: " + request.getFirstHeader("Authorization: Bearer"));
        request.setEntity(params);
        System.out.println("sending Request-------------------------------------------------------------------------->");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for (Header header : headers) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName() 
            + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());
        }
```

I got access_token from Access control server and I am trying to use that and get SAS URI but while passing the token in header I am getting HTTP response code as 500.(I missed the trailing "/" in scope while generating token thats why I was getting 401 error)

API document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn800660(v=vs.85).aspx

output:

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Content-Type: text/html, Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5, X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, Date: Tue, 05 Jul 2016 19:36:02 GMT,
Content-Length: 1293] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/html,Content-
Length: 1293,Chunked: false]}}
Key : Content-Type ,Value : text/html
Key : Server ,Value : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Key : X-Powered-By ,Value : ASP.NET
Key : Date ,Value : Tue, 05 Jul 2016 19:36:02 GMT
Key : Content-Length ,Value : 1293
```

Enabling log:

```
2016/07/05 16:27:40:237 EDT [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
2016/07/05 16:27:40:237 EDT [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
2016/07/05 16:27:40:238 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://devicesigningservice.cloudapp.net:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2016/07/05 16:27:40:238 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 1][route: {s}->https://devicesigningservice.cloudapp.net:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2016/07/05 16:27:40:238 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://devicesigningservice.cloudapp.net:443
2016/07/05 16:27:40:240 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to devicesigningservice.cloudapp.net/191.246.47.593:843
2016/07/05 16:27:40:240 EDT [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to devicesigningservice.cloudapp.net/191.246.47.593:843 with timeout 0
2016/07/05 16:27:40:256 EDT [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2016/07/05 16:27:40:256 EDT [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2016/07/05 16:27:40:256 EDT [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
2016/07/05 16:27:40:517 EDT [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
2016/07/05 16:27:40:517 EDT [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
2016/07/05 16:27:40:517 EDT [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
2016/07/05 16:27:40:517 EDT [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=devicesigningservice.cloudapp.net
2016/07/05 16:27:40:517 EDT [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [devicesigningservice.cloudapp.net]
2016/07/05 16:27:40:517 EDT [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2, OU=Microsoft IT, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, ST=Washington, C=US
2016/07/05 16:27:40:518 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 9.82.117.101:65081<->191.246.47.593:843
2016/07/05 16:27:40:518 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Executing request POST /api/signing/devices HTTP/1.1
2016/07/05 16:27:40:518 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2016/07/05 16:27:40:518 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> POST /api/signing/devices HTTP/1.1
2016/07/05 16:27:40:518 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Type: application/json
2016/07/05 16:27:40:518 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Authorization: Bearer http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%blah%bla
2016/07/05 16:27:40:518 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Length: 181
2016/07/05 16:27:40:518 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Host: devicesigningservice.cloudapp.net
2016/07/05 16:27:40:519 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2016/07/05 16:27:40:519 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_77)
2016/07/05 16:27:40:519 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2016/07/06 15:14:19:022 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
2016/07/06 15:14:19:022 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Cache-Control: no-cache
2016/07/06 15:14:19:022 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Pragma: no-cache
2016/07/06 15:14:19:022 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2016/07/06 15:14:19:022 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Expires: -1
2016/07/06 15:14:19:023 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
2016/07/06 15:14:19:023 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
2016/07/06 15:14:19:023 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
2016/07/06 15:14:19:023 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2016 19:14:18 GMT
2016/07/06 15:14:19:023 EDT [DEBUG] headers - http-outgoing-1 << Content-Length: 36
2016/07/06 15:14:19:023 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
```

Answer (score 2):

Change following line

```
request.setHeader("Authorization: Bearer ", access_token);
```

to

```
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
```

Comment: I did the above mentioned change still I am getting the same error.

Comment: That was the first error :) post your code after the change and the output that you're getting.

Comment: yea,true that. Output still remains the same.I have added the part where I pass token to the method.

Comment: 401 means that Authorization header wasn't sent to server, if it recognizes the header and token is invalid then it should return 403. Check the network call, if network call has the Authorization header. Also you can validate if the service is working from the REST client plugin from the browser first to rule out server side error.

Comment: From the logs it seems that `Authorization` header was sent. Are you able to access the service using some REST client ?

Comment: There is a web version where I can manually upload file for signing the driver and it is working but as per the document provided fro REST API :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn800660(v=vs.85).aspx this is what I am suppose to do in 3rd step.